# Hide a column in flexigrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

Is there a way to hide and show a column in jQuery flexigrid like this?

```
$('#FlexigridID').hideCol('ColumnName');
$('#FlexigridID').showCol('ColumnName');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New code tested:

```
$(function () {


    var visible = true;
    $('#yo').click(function () {
        alert('hello');

        visible = !visible;
        showColumn('#yourFlexigridNameHere', 'Lastname', visible);
    });

});


// you can put this in a separate javascript library
function showColumn(tbl, columnName, visible) {

    var grd = $(tbl).closest('.flexigrid');
    var colHeader = $('th[abbr=' + columnName + ']', grd);
    var colIndex = $(colHeader).attr('axis').replace(/col/, "");


    // queryVisible = $(colHeader).is(':visible');
    // alert(queryVisible);

    $(colHeader).toggle(visible);

    $('tbody tr', grd).each(
        function () {
            $('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')', this).toggle(visible);
        }
    );

}
```

HTML:

```
<input id='yo' type="button" />
```

---

You can also set the hide to false on flexigrid's colModel setup:

```
colModel: [
    {display: 'Row ID', name : 'Lastname', width : 100, 
     sortable : true, align: 'left', hide: false}
```

---

You can also add a method against flexigrid, you can put this in a separate javascript library:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.showColumn = function (columnName, visible) {        

        if (visible == undefined) visible = true;

        var grd = this.closest('.flexigrid');        
        var colHeader = $('th[abbr=' + columnName + ']', grd);
        var colIndex = $(colHeader).attr('axis').replace(/col/, "");

        $(colHeader).toggle(visible);

        $('tbody tr', grd).each(
            function () {                
                $('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')', this).toggle(visible);
            }
        ); 
    };

    $.fn.hideColumn = function (columnName) {
        this.showColumn(columnName, false);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

You can now invoke hiding and showing using these:

```
$('#FlexigridID').hideColumn('ColumnName');
$('#FlexigridID').showColumn('ColumnName');


visible = !visible; // for toggling need
$('#FlexigridID').showColumn('ColumnName', visible);
```

Comment: @Michaeal: It's not working for my grid. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: It works. I can setup colModel. But am looking for single line of code. I have many flexigrids in my project and I need to hide columns for some cases.

Comment: move the `function showColumn(tbl, columnName, visible){...}` to a javascript library, so it's reusable. then just call `showColumn('#yourFlexigridNameHere','Lastname',false)`

Comment: @MichaelBuen: This is only hiding the "header" (title) of the column and not the actual data, the data is still there after doing hideColumn. Any idea why?

Comment: @Mathias hmm.. I tested that, it works, it hides both header and the data. But maybe you are using the latest version of flexigrid and its HTML and css class changes, I haven't use flexigrid for long time. Try to use the browser's Inspect Element and see if the flexigrid HTML structure and class corresponds to the code above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#FlexigridID').find("tr td").eq(columnIndex).hide();
$('#FlexigridID').find("tr td").eq(columnIndex).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

for table with header(th)

```
$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Read more about [Hide a Table Column with a Single line of jQuery code](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/hide-table-column-with-single-line-of.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourFlexigridNameHere").flexToggleCol(columnIndex, false);
//columnIndex - starts from 0
```